# When not to use prebuilt CMS?

Tags: asp.net, .net, content-management-system, dotnetnuke, umbraco

Is there any case that creating your own CMS for a specialized website more advantageous than using a prebuilt CMS such as dotnetnuke or umbraco? Can anyone site a project when they had to create a custom CMS and not used a prebuilt CMS? Where to draw the line from using a prebuilt CMS to a customize CMS? Or is using prebuilt CMS always more advantageous than building your own CMS in any type of content driven website?

Comment: Perhaps the programmer doesn't like some technology or style choices made by the CMS. For example I would avoid any WebForms based CMS. Or he dislikes the architecture, or the required persistence layer.

Comment: I think it depends an on the experience of the programmer on that prebuilt CMS.

Answer (score 3):

With the quality and variety of current open source offerings, I would say it's almost never a good idea to start from scratch. It really comes down to requirements and features. There's a huge variety in the features and user experience of different systems out there. You really need to figure out the priorities (performance vs. ease of use vs. flexibility vs. extensibility vs. SEO) to choose the right one.

I generally go with DotNetNuke with an assortment of custom modules to enhance aspects of its CMS and SEO capabilities. There's just not much you can't do with DNN once you really get to know it. But if performance is your highest priority, another option might be preferred.

Comment: ok but is using dotnetnuke just going to replace everything you know about webforms or asp .net mvc or is it just going to enhance how you develop websites (by adding customizable controls/modules/components, etc?) inside visual studio?

Comment: Development within DNN is similar, just a few tweaks.  It follows the webforms model.

Comment: DNN adds lots of additional functionality on top of ASP.NET WebForms. The one caveat there is the skinning side of things. ASP.NET 2.0 uses Master Pages. DNN, does not use Master Pages. it has it's own Skins/Containers model. There are differences but ultimately I find them very similar to work with. Both are quite unlimited in what you can do.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends what the overall goal of the project is. If you are building a marketing website or your project can be easily accomplished with a pre-built CMS then you should certainly start there and build modules or customize a little if needed.

However, if you are building a web application that's core functionality is not just content, page management you have to consider going a custom route.  Pintrest, Facebook, Flickr, etc. would definitely not start with a pre-fab CMS.

The Onion started with Drupal at one point but realized their needs were so custom that they ended up doing it all in Python/Django.  Plus, with frameworks like Python/Django and Ruby on Rails if you are building web apps you can easily create the CMS features you need.

We do a lot of DotNetNuke, some Drupal and all of our custom web apps we are doing with Ruby on Rails. Once you have the requirements and goals of the project you have to look at your tools and see what is the best for the job. And sometimes it's making your own tools :]

Answer (score 1):

if you move for a prebuilt CMS, you have to use their available functions and do improve whatever your features. but if you go fro a new custom CMS, you are free to customized to the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

What are your requirements? If the majority of your requirements (65% +) are CMS related requirements, than I would strongly recommend looking into existing CMS solutions (opensource or commercial).

On other hand, if your CMS requirements are about 35% of your total requirements, then I would consider implementing in-house, fairly light-weight CMS.

Be aware, CMS sounds like an interesting and easy to tackle task, but when it comes to it, it is likely to be the most complicated project that you have ever worked on, mainly due to its extensibility, security and efficiency related requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what the requirements are for the project.